# RDPStruct.exe: what is it and why are there so many?

Tags: version-7, webmathematica

I have an old (v7) webMathematica system running and it seems to generate a lot of RDPStruct.exe processes.

First, what does this "Converter" do? GIF.exe and JPEG.exe are obvious, but "RDPStruct" doesn't mean anything to me.

Does it make sense for there to be more than one running at a time? Does it make sense for there to be like 20 running at a time? Are they being orphaned somehow? If so, how can I figure out which ones are no longer in use?

They seem to be causing system problems. I also have some command-line Mathematica processes that stop functioning properly sometimes and I find that killing off the RDPStruct processes will make them start working again.  I don't yet have a lot of detail around this yet.

Comment: What did you do precisely to trigger the launching of these processes?

Comment: I don't know.  It's customer-facing, and I don't know how to correlate input with these processes.

Comment: Sorry.  That's a sign I should get some sleep and keep off the site for a while ...

Comment: Some spelunking suggests that the process might be used during GIF exporting.